# Was offered higher salary "later", do I push for "sooner"?

Tags: salary, job-offer, career, compensation

1. At company X, I was offered a job at "The new office", A, which "We will be opening soon".
2. The manager of the "new office" resigned, office A did not materialize.
3. While a replacement for the manager was sought, my contract got placed with office B, while I started work at office C, which is across a nearby country border.
4. Six months ago, everyone agreed that I would stay at C for now, and so my contract was transferred there.

At the time, I was only vaguely aware that salaries were higher across the border. Now my current boss, at C, has without previous inquiry from me on the subject sent me an e-mail saying, in short

> You are entitled to a higher salary, in 6 months you'll get a 20% raise.

My question is, if I *should* have a higher salary, is there a reason I should wait 6 months to get it? Is there a reason I should not have it retro-actively? Am I just being greedy?

I read the [FAQ](https://money.stackexchange.com/faq), but I'm still uncertain as to whether this is on-topic or not.
After reading this meta question [are-questions-about-careers-off-topic](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279/are-questions-about-careers-off-topic), I decided to post.

Comment: This question is off topic because it is soliciting opinions on what you should do.

Comment: But you couldn't help answering it anyway? ;) I can see what you mean, it is hard (or impossible?) to come up with a "right" answer to the question.

Comment: I addressed the parts of the question I could.  This would be a good question for [The Workplace](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30887/the-workplace?referrer=wofscIY3-VGJS6wd42Y-3w2) Currently in commitment phase at Area51.  Please go and commit to supporting this community.  It should be in beta very soon

Comment: @Chad I'm also looking forward to The Workplace SE .. I committed last week.

Answer (score 4):

The question is why are you entitled to a higher salary? '

If it is a contract or minimum wage consideration then you absolutely have the right to ask for an immediate raise.  It is also possible that the contract/raise will take place in 6 months and that is when you will be entitled to it.

If you are not actually entitled to it but your company feels that the range for the position is  between $X and $Y and your current salary is 20% below $X then you are not truly entitled to it.

I would approach it with my manager and ask him why I am entitled to this 20% raise.  Ask him/her why it will take 6 months to get it. Those are answers you can then use to make your decision.

Comment: There is no contract or otherwise legal obligation involved, rather, as you suggest, my employer feels that my position and skills warrant a higher pay. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @user50849 - how come there is no contract but you refer to "my contract was transferred."  Maybe you should ask for that contract.

Comment: My apologies for being unclear. I do have a contract for my job, where in my current salary is specified. There is no contract however giving me the raise in question.

Comment: @user50849: If there is no contract for a raise, then the company is proactively letting you know that you will get 20% more. They are doing this probably so that you will not look out elsewhere for other job. You can negotiate for immediate raise, but it can go against you as well.

Comment: Yes, which is exactly my point. :) Perhaps I should update the question, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: @user50849 - I am not sure what you are thinking of asking that would be on topic.  I think the part of the question you want answered(what should you do about your job) is very much off topic here.  This is a QA about personal finance.   Once  [The Workplace](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30887/the-workplace?referrer=wofscIY3-VGJS6wd42Y-3w2) opens, in the next week hopefully, this question should be on topic there.  SE works well because we keep our QA's on topic.

Comment: No, realize that it is not on topic, I'm expecting a mod to close it. I cannot do it myself anymore since there is an answer. :)